# Intuition behind Schur's Triangulization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> **Schur's Unitary Triangulization Theorem**: For every square matrix A there exists some unitary matrix $U$ such that
>   $$U^*AU=T$$
>   where $T$ is an upper triangular matrix with diagonal elements equal to the eigenvalues of $A$.

What's the intuition behind this theorem?

Apparently, it's equivalent to: *for every nxn matrix, there exists an orthonormal basis in which the matrix is upper triangular.* - but I don't see how.

Please help me out here!

Also, the choice of $U$ doesn't seem unique, so what's the best way to compute $U$?

Comment: Householder has a classical paper on how to compute it: https://www.stat.uchicago.edu/~lekheng/courses/302/classics/householder.pdf